# Операция приведения типов С++

Tags: c++, function-overloading

Есть два класса A и B как реализовать приведение типов друг в друга?

```
class A
{
...
    operator B()
    {
        return B(5);
    }
};

class B
{
...
    operator A()
    {
        return A(5);
    }
};
```

Пробовал писать объявление до определения, не помогает.

Answer (score 4):

В C++ разрешение зависимостей определений классов устроено следующим образом:

Если в некотором месте кода встречается имя класса, то к этому моменту этот класс уже должен быть определён. Есть два варианта определения класса:

1. `class A;`
2. `class A { ... }`

Определять класс первым способом можно сколько угодно раз, вторым способом только один раз. Второй тип определения более сильный, так как второй тип определения фиксирует структуру класса. В определении второго типа можно опустить реализацию некоторых методов, и написать их позже (считается хорошей практикой писать определение класса в `.h` файле, а реализацию в соответствующем `.cpp` файле). Вот [хорошая статья](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) на эту тему.

Таким образом, решение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class A;
class B;

class A {
public:
    operator B();
};

class B {
public:
    operator A();
};

A::operator B() {
    return B();
}

B::operator A() {
    return A();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b = (B) a;
    A a2 = (A) b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Один класс (выберите по своему вкусу :)) вынести в предварительное объявление, а его *использование* - после определения класса:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    operator B() const;
};

class B
{
public:
    operator A() const { cout << "B::A()\n"; return A(); }
};

inline A::operator B() const { cout << "A::B()\n"; return B(); }

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a = b;
    b = a;
}
```